# Ansible playbook to look for a non-default "group_vars" folder for vault passwords

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am trying to write an ansible playbook that can configure devices that are not in inventory yet.

I have been successful in configuring the devices with commands etc
However, I am looking to configure `snmp` passwords on this device that are stored in `group_vars/cisco-ios`

```
group_vars
all
cisco-ios  - THIS ONE
etc
etc
etc
```

Since this device isn't in the inventory yet, ansible does not know that this is a "cisco-ios" ( TO go pull vault passwords from cisco-ios folder ), it is ONLY looking for group_vars/all ( where my passwords aren't stored and we cannot store it here since it will break all other devices )

Looking for suggestions on how I can force ansible to look for group_vars/cisco-ios for vault  passwords instead of group_vars/all??

Tried hardcoding the device_os to 'cisco-ios', tried pointing the --vault-password-file to the cisco-ios etc

As of now, my jinja2 template has : snmp-server community {{ password }} 
It return back saying "password" is undefined
( However if I use a password in group_vars/all - works perfectly fine )

Answer (score 0):

Why not using an `includes_vars` to force the load of the variables set you want?

```
- name: Include vars for 'cisco-ios'
  include_vars:
    file: group_vars/cisco-ios

- name: Check that I have the password for Cisco devices
  debug:
    var: password
```

Comment: Great suggestion xenlo. I did add the above lines, but it still does not know to pull the variables from vault, it is good that it is atleast reaching the file. I think now the final piece is to go tell it to pull from vault

Comment: any suggestions on how I can do that?

Comment: What do you mean by pull the variable from the vault?

Comment: Is your `password` variable define in `group_vars/cisco-ios` encrypted and starting with `!vault` tag (or maybe you sub files `group_vars/cisco-ios/vars` & `group_vars/cisco-ios/vault`)? In anyway, Ansible should see that this variable is encrypted and if you provide the right password should be able to read it on the fly...

Comment: the variables under the group_vars/all are encrypted but not the one under group_vars/cisco-ios